# Followed default options in installation, now have a tiny drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I spent a small fortune (6k) and made five server racks. 
I have purchased Five m.2 samsung drives that run nearly at 2250 MBps.
I followed basic directions of the latest ubuntu os when installing it. 
Something is wrong, the drives I have installed have 128GB capacity where as this is what my df prints out.

```
    Filesystem                   1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
    udev                          16402568        0  16402568   0% /dev
    tmpfs                          3282848   320392   2962456  10% /run
    /dev/mapper/server5--vg-root  89780400 59506456  25690316  70% /
    tmpfs                         16414228        0  16414228   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                             5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs                         16414228        0  16414228   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/sda1                       240972   240139         0 100% /boot
    tmpfs                          3282848        0   3282848   0% /run/user/1000
```

Note that each machine also has 32 GB ram.

Also some of my info from the start up screen

```
    System load:  1.16               Processes:           173
      Usage of /:   65.8% of 85.62GB   Users logged in:     0
      Memory usage: 24%
```

So why is only 89 gigs allocated? How do I increase the partition size? This is a problem as I am starting to run out of disk space across all my machines.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only chose to allocate that much when you installed.  To increase it now you can do:

```
sudo lvresize -L 100g server5-vg/root
sudo resize2fs /dev/server5-vg/root
```

Comment: I didn't see an option. Can I do a command to find exact side therefore using max?

Comment: @user2656801, `sudo pvs` will show how much unallocated space you have in the volume group or if you want to use it all you can specify "100%" for the size, but using it all in a single volume kind of defeats the purpose of using LVM.

Comment: root@server5:~# pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
          /dev/sda5  server5-vg lvm2 a--  119.00g    0
        root@server5:~# lvresize -L 119g server5-vg/root
  Insufficient free space: 8163 extents needed, but only 0 available
        root@server5:~# lvresize -L 118g server5-vg/root
  Insufficient free space: 7907 extents needed, but only 0 available
        root@server5:~# lvresize -L 100g server5-vg/root
  Insufficient free space: 3299 extents needed, but only 0 available
        root@server5:~#

Comment: @user2656801, how big is sda5?  You might just need to use `sudo pvresize` on it to grow it to the full partition size, or you might need to resize the partition first.  You can do this using `parted`.